Implement thread safe deque
As part of a server application to run on macOS, I need to implement a thread-safe deque in order to feed jobs to a thread pool. I'm new to Swift.
In C++ it would look like:
class JobQueue
{
public:
    size_t size()
    {
        mGuard.lock(mMutex);
        return mJobFifo.size()
    }
    
    void push(const Job &job)
    {
        mGuard.lock(mMutex);
        mJobFifo.push_back(job);
    }

    Job pop()
    {
        mGuard.lock(mMutex);
        Job tmp = mJobFifo.front();
        mJobFifo.pop_front();
        return tmp;
    }   
    
private:
    std::deqeue<Job>            mJobFifo;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mGuard;
    std::mutex                  mMutex;
}

In Swift, I've tried the code below but size() always returns zero despite the backing Deque having many elements.
I've read a few articles saying to use mQueue.async(flags: .barrier) to lock exclusive access (like std::lock_guard ??) but the function's return value is not updated.
I also tried putting the return ret inside the .async, but it gave the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to closure result type 'Void'":
    mQueue.async(flags: .barrier)
    {
        ret = self.mJobFifo.count
        print("internal size: \(ret)")
        return ret
    }

Is this the best way to implement such a thread-safe queue? If so, then what am I doing wrong? If not, then how should it be done?
import Foundation
import DequeModule
class OcrJob
{
    static var lastJobId : Int = 0
    var jobId : Int
    
    init()
    {
        jobId = OcrJob.lastJobId
        OcrJob.lastJobId += 1
    }
}

class OcrJobQueue
{
    init(max: UInt)
    { 
        mMaxSize = max
    }
    
    public func size() -> Int
    {
        var ret = 0
        mQueue.async(flags: .barrier)
        {
            ret = self.mJobFifo.count
            print("internal size: \(ret)")
        }
        
        print("size returns \(ret). ")
        return ret
    }
    
    public func pushBack(job: OcrJob) throws
    {
        let curSize = mJobFifo.count
        guard (curSize < mMaxSize) else
        {
            print("pushBack - curSize: \(curSize), mMaxSize \(mMaxSize)")
            throw QueueError.full
        }
        
        mQueue.async(flags: .barrier)
        {
            self.mJobFifo.append(job)
            print("pushBack: \(self.mJobFifo.count) jobs in queue")
        }
    }
    
    public func popFirst() -> OcrJob?
    {
        var ret : OcrJob? = nil
        mQueue.async(flags: .barrier)
        {
            ret = self.mJobFifo.popFirst()
            print("popFirst: \(self.mJobFifo.count) jobs in queue")
        }
        
        return ret
    }
    
    private var mMaxSize : UInt = 10
    private var mQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "JobQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var mJobFifo : Deque<OcrJob> = []
    
}


See if NSOperationQueue can meet your needs or you can use a Swift actor

Thanks, I'll look into NSOperationsQueue. I've read a bit about actor already but it is not obvious to me on how to apply that to the problem. Wouldn't a collection of actor objects equate to a collection of std::thread workers, who pull jobs out of the queue?

An actor prevents concurrent access to its state.  So, a worker can call pop to get a task. The pop implementation can update the queue safely without needing to perform any explicit synchronisation or guarding

You also have a concurrency issue with your OcrJob class because of the static lastJobId property.  I would suggest you use a uuid instead of an integer as the job id to avoid this.

Probably the simplest way to solve this is to make use of Swift actors.  An actor isolates access to its mutable state.
I would also change OcrJob to be a struct so that it is a value type, and eliminate the static property, because that is more mutable state to be concerned with.
struct OcrJob {

   let jobId = UUID()

}

actor OcrJobQueue {

    let maxSize: UInt
    private var jobFifo = [OcrJob]()

    init(max: UInt = 10)
    { 
        maxSize = max
    }

    public var size: Int 
    {
        return self.jobFifo.count
    }
    
    public func pushBack(job: OcrJob) throws
    {
        guard (jobFifo.count < maxSize) else
        {
            throw QueueError.full
        }
        jobFifo.append(job)
    }
    
    public func popFirst() -> OcrJob?
    {
        guard !self.jobFifo.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        return self.jobFifo.removeFirst()
    }
}

Note that you will now need to interact with your OcrJobQueue in an asynchronous context -
await jobQueue.pushBack(job: someJob)

let nextJob = await jobQueue.popFirst()

